# Android: Supporting Multiple Screens

Tags: android

Have a question...Android divides the range of actual screen sizes and densities into: A set of four generalized sizes: small, normal, large, and xlarge.
A set of four generalized densities: ldpi (low), mdpi (medium), hdpi (high), and xhdpi (extra high)

1) What have the higher priority ?

Lats say I have hdpi device with large screen size...And I have 2 folders in my project: 'layout-large' and 'layout-hdpi'...Which folder will use my device ?

2) I have hdpi device and 2 folders in my project...default 'layout' folder and 'layou-mdpi'
   Why hdpi use layou-mdpi ?

3) How to name folder correctly ? layout-mdpi-normal or layout-normal-mdpi...

Thanks...

Comment: 1 and 3 can be simply tested... 2 is a good question

Comment: 1) Looks like screen size have higher priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I guess that the priority respect the naming convenction for these folders, layout-mmc-language-screensize..... and so. But I don't have tested it. So I think that screen size will be choosen first.

2) layout-hdpi uses layout-mdpi because it's the best candidate (it is the folder that theoretically should fit better with the hdpi screen, because layout it's totally generic)

3)layout-normal-mdpi

Comment: 2)I dont understand why hdpi take values from folder layout-mdpi...Where is logic ? It should take from default folder Layout... =)

Comment: I think that the logic it's: layout/ can be anything. layout-mdpi can't be too much different. So I choose layout-mdpi