# How to design app for multiple screens

Tags: android, xml

I've designed my UI in pixels(px) in the dimensions 700x400. Is it possible to stretch the ui along with the different phones?

Comment: Yes, of course its streach.

Comment: try to maintain the same image with different pixels in different drawable folders...

Comment: don't use pixels use dip and sp(for text fonts)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Supporting Multiple Screens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304935/android-supporting-multiple-screens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use dp while designing android layout.
Have a look on following url for better understanding of multiple screen support in android. http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/07/how-to-support-multiple-screen-in.html

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in dp and for different screen size should use different values mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi etc. Not only drawable but possibly different  layouts and values for width, height, paddings, margins etc

Answer (score 1):

*You have to do it manually !*

- Create different folders of name **layout-small**,
  **layout-large**,
  **layout-xlarge**
  in **res**  folder
- Copy-paste all ur .xml's from ur layout to thes folder
- Open all the xml's & set the margins with using different screen sizes one by one
- Then u can run & see the app in different size emulators

Answer (score 1):

Make different xml files for different layouts. You have to put the xml files in the folders accordingly(You have to keep the layout names and the id's same in each of them) Make folders like **layout-land**, **Layout-Normal-Land**, **layout-xlarge** etc. You also need different drawable for different screen density. You can create folders accordingly like-  **drawable-small-mdpi**, **drawable-large-hdpi** and others.

Answer (score 0):

have different drawable for different screen size check [this](http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html) for more info